# How to watermark PDF files using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, pdf, thymeleaf, watermark

How to watermark PDF files using thymeleaf or should I be using iText or other libraries. Would prefer to use thymeleaf, not sure what interfaces are available for that

```
// thymeleaf
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
implementation group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer', name: 'flying-saucer-pdf', version: '9.1.22'
```

Comment: Thymeleaf doesn't generate PDF files, so trying to use a non-PDF library to watermark PDFs will not work.

Comment: What should be used then?